# VBA Dictionary for uniqueness count

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am in need of a macro that finds all the unique names in a list and then counts them. I then need to display them on another excel page.

After reading up on it I think the best way to do this is with a Dictionary? But after several attempts myself I cant seem to crack it.

Example list:
- Apple
- Orange
- Banana
- Banana
- Orange
- Pear

Output would be:
Apple     1
Orange    2
Banana    2
Pear      1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the basic idea - Use the item you want to count as the key, and the count itself as the value.  If it is already in the Dictionary, increment it.  If not, add it:

```
Const TEST_DATA = "Apple,Orange,Banana,Banana,Orange,Pear"

Sub Example()
    Dim counter As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim testData() As String

    testData = Split(TEST_DATA, ",")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(testData) To UBound(testData)
        If Not counter.Exists(testData(i)) Then
            counter.Add testData(i), 1
        Else
            counter.Item(testData(i)) = counter.Item(testData(i)) + 1
        End If
    Next 

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In counter.Keys
        Debug.Print key, counter(key)
    Next      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a big help.

Comment: This code produces a "User-defined type not defined" error on the `Dim counter As New Scripting.Dictionary` line unless you set a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" via Tools > References

Comment: @barrowc - Alternately you can replace that line with `Dim counter As Object: Set counter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

Comment: I would have preferred to use late binding.  Still good work +1