# Subscript out of range error for dynamic array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to loop through columns in an array, check if the values are unique, and then count the number of times a given string appears in the array.

Any time I pass a `UBound` or `LBound` command I get

> subscript out of range

Asterisks are comments for this post and not in code.

*code snippet that is having issue

```vb
Dim uniqueValues() As Variant
Dim occurrences() As Variant
Dim partNumber As String
Dim partNumberRange As Range
                
Erase uniqueValues
Erase occurrences
                
Dim tempVar1 As String
Dim tempVar2 As String
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

'*fastenerSheets array is defined elsewhere                
Set partNumberRange = fastenerSheets(i - 1).Range("A2", "A" & CStr(diameterTestCount(i - 1) + 1))
Debug.Print partNumberRange.Address
                
Dim cell As Variant
For Each cell In partNumberRange
    partNumber = cell.value
    Debug.Print partNumber
    If IsInArray(partNumber, uniqueValues) Then
        ' If yes, find its index and increment the occurrences
        For j = LBound(uniqueValues) To UBound(uniqueValues)
            If uniqueValues(j) = partNumber Then
                Debug.Print uniqueValues(j)
                occurrences(j) = occurrences(j) + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        ' If no, add the value to uniqueValues and set occurrences to 1

        '*code fails here trying to assign value k
        k = UBound(uniqueValues) + 1
        ReDim Preserve uniqueValues(1 To k)
        ReDim Preserve occurrences(1 To k)
        uniqueValues(k) = partNumber
        occurrences(k) = 1
    End If
Next cell
```

*function that is called in the snippet

```vb
Function IsInArray(val As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, val)) > -1)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: I guess you try to keep unique list in `uniqueValues` and store its count in `occurrences`. If so, using `Dictionary` object is a better approach. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261503/vba-dictionary-for-uniqueness-count

Comment: Worth noting that `Filter()` filters both on whole values *and on substrings* so it's not a very safe way to check if a particular value is in an array.  Eg: `? Filter(Array("AAA","BBB"),"AA")(0)` will give you "AAA".

Comment: Especially with `365`, you can do this simply with a worksheet formula. Is that something of interest?

Comment: Please share the complete code and what you're planning to do with the resulting arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Dictionary` object is a better approach to get unique list and count

```
Dim cell As Variant, objDic as Object, sKey
Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In partNumberRange
     partNumber = cell.value
     If objDic.exists(partNumber) Then
        objDic(partNumber) = objDic(partNumber) + 1
     Else
        objDic(partNumber) = 1
     End If
Next cell
' Check the unique list
For Each sKey in objDic.keys
    Debug.Print sKey, objDic(sKey) 
Next
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are 'empty', so they have no bounds.
Either assign some value initially or create an error checker.

See these links 
[check if array is empty (vba excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290781/check-if-array-is-empty-vba-excel) 
https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?736285-VB6-Returning-Detecting-Empty-Arrays